# How does editing lists in function work

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble understanding lists:

```
mList = []
def func1(mList):
    mList.append("1")
    return
func1()
print mList
```

As I understand it because a list is mutable, if I edit it in a function, the main list will also be edited. In a program I am working on this is happening with one list which I am using as a "save file", however, a second list which I am using as a "value_blacklist" is not being saved after it is edited/added to.

I included the problem part of the actual code I am having issues with if it's of any help.

```
def func04(feedback, test_list, value_blacklist, upper_limit=6):
    if value_blacklist == []:
            value_blacklist = blacklist_gen(length)
       import random
       new_list = []
        for index in list(range(0, len(feedback))):
        if feedback[index] == 0: #This value is correct, leave it
            new_list.append(test_list[index])
        elif feedback[index] == 2:
            value_blacklist = full_blacklist(test_list[index], value_blacklist)
            new_list.append(0)
        elif feedback[index] == 1:
            value_blacklist[index].append(test_list[index])
            new_list.append(0)
    for index in list(range(0, len(feedback))):
        if new_list[index] == 0:
            new_list[index] = pick_new(index, value_blacklist, upper_limit)
    return new_list

next_guess = lambda: func04(feedback(), save_game[-1], value_blacklist, save_game[0])
```

Thanks for any help, I'm really confused by this.

Comment: FWIW, in your example code, you need to pass the list to `func1()` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `=` operator in a function, you are not modifying the existing object. Right hand side of the expression creates a new list and returns a reference to it and that reference is assigned to `value_blacklist`.

```
value_blacklist = blacklist_gen(length)
...
value_blacklist = full_blacklist(test_list[index], value_blacklist)
```

These are the places where you create new local lists and referring them with `value_blacklist`. That's why `value_blacklist` doesn't reflect the changes. You can confirm this by printing the `id` of `value_blacklist` after the assignment statements and at the beginning of the function.

Comment: The idea is right but the wording is not. Assignment doesn't "create a new local object."

Comment: @MattBall Can you please check now? I think I explained better this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, couldn't figure out what was wrong for absolutly ages. It works perfectly now.

Comment: I wish I could upvote. I need 15 rep though, I'm rather new here. I had to wait the 15 or so mins before I could accept your answer as well. Thanks again though. (EDIT: I can +rep now, there you go, your well earned rep)

Answer (score 2):

Whereever you are saying

```
value_blacklist = ...
```

You are *rebinding* `value_blacklist` to a new (list) object. If you instead say

```
value_blacklist[:] = ...
```

You will replace the contents of the list without rebinding it.

Ask lots of questions until you really really understand this. It's very important to "get" it.

Comment: Yup I understand now. Your option is a much faster way to change it than what I did to fix it. I actually changed the function to append to the blacklist there. Thanks for the help!